# How to execute python string over time?

Tags: python, string, time

Say I have a bunch of lines ''' ......''' And I don't want every one of them popping out at the same time, how do I create a delay between them?

Or better yet, everyone remember the matrix scene at the beginning with the "follow the white rabbit, knock knock". How do you do that, just have it look as if it's being written live.

THanks guys in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have some text

```
text= '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
         Donec rhoncus est augue, eget vulputate elit vulputate ut. 
         Maecenas et tellus eget enim consectetur facilisis ut vitae ante. Donec ut feugiat elit.''''
```

You can use `print` and `time.sleep` for a brief period so it'll seem like it is being typed at the time. You can use some `random` sampling from an interval for the `sleep` to make it seem not so 'scripted'

```
import random 

for char in text:
    print(char,end='')
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.01, 0.05))
```

Comment: Yea, that's almost what I was looking for. thx I think i can figure it out form here.
P.S. I think you need to import time, right?